# TypeError: draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen'

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, typeerror

I've looked around on here for solutions to this problem with no avail. Maybe you can help, I can't see the error.

Here's the traceback:

```
  File "copy.py", line 171, in <module>
    main()
  File "copy.py", line 128, in main
    game.draw(screen)
  File "copy.py", line 59, in draw
    snake.draw(screen)
TypeError: draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen'
```

The code referenced in the trace back is below

```
def main():
    pygame.init()

    winWidth, winHeight = 800, 800
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([winWidth, winHeight])
    pygame.display.set_caption("Exploring mouse, keys, and event loops with Pygame")

    running = 1
    bgcolor = (0,0,0)
    screen.fill(bgcolor)

    game = SnaketheGame(winWidth, winHeight)
    game.draw(screen)

##########
class SnaketheGame:
    def __init__(self, winWidth, winHeight):

        self.snake = snake
        self.snakeMoving = False
        self.growingSnake = False
        self.food = food

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.snake.draw(screen)
        for food in self.food:
            food.draw(screen)
```

I've looked through other answers and made sure that I was calling an instance of the class first. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Please help!

Comment: Is that all of your code for the SnaketheGame class? I'm just curious what the initializer looks like.

Comment: @JennerFelton This isn't all my code in the class, I just tried to trim out the non-useful bits. I've edited my original post to include my init.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but are `snake` and `food` globally defined then?

Comment: @JennerFelton It looks like they aren't defined yet. My partner wrote most of this code and it's still incomplete, so I'll have to ask him. We're both stuck on this error though.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, I believe that when you are calling `game = SnaketehGame(winWidth, winHeight)`, you aren't actually initializing the game. Because you haven't defined `snake` and `food`, it's probably not initializing correctly, so when you try to call `game.draw`, you don't actually have a game yet, so the `screen` input is being used in place of `self`. This is why you are getting the error that you don't have the positional argument of `screen`: `screen` is being used as `self`.

To fix this, fix your initialization to define `snake` and `food`.